# How to avoid edges overlap in multigraph when using taxi edges?

Tags: cytoscape.js

```js
let styleJson = JSON.parse(`
      [{
        "selector": "node",
        "style": {
          "label": "data(id)",
          "height": "data(height)",
          "width": "data(width)",
          "text-valign": "center",
          "text-halign": "center"
        }
      }, {
        "selector": "node.begin-end",
        "style": {
          "shape": "ellipse",
          "width": "70",
          "height": "30"
        }
      }, {
        "selector": "node.if",
        "style": {
          "shape": "diamond"
        }
      }, {
        "selector": "edge",
        "style": {
          "width": 2,
          "label": "data(id)",
          "curve-style": "taxi"
        }
      }, {
        "selector": "edge.true",
        "style": {
          "taxi-direction": "rightward"
        }
      }, {
        "selector": "edge.false",
        "style": {
          "taxi-direction": "leftward"
        }
      }]
    `);

let cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  style: styleJson,
  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'begin'
        },
        classes: 'begin-end'
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'if',
          width: "70",
          height: "30"
        },
        classes: 'if'
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'end',
          width: "70",
          height: "30"
        },
        classes: 'begin-end'
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n1',
          source: 'begin',
          target: 'if'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2',
          source: 'if',
          target: 'end'
        },
        classes: 'true'
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n3',
          source: 'if',
          target: 'end'
        },
        classes: 'false'
      }
    ]
  }
});

doLayout();

function doLayout() {
  let layoutOpts = {
    name: 'breadthfirst',
    directed: true
  };
  cy.layout(layoutOpts).run();
}
```

```css
#cy {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cytoscape</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="cy"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape@3.17.1/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I just want to split the 2 edges coming from IF node.
The direction is specified (leftward/rightward), but I don't know how to make it working...